# Web page not rendering correctly in iOS browsers or desktop Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I've got a simple webpage. Just a header, an unordered list, and a background image.

The background image is blurred with CSS:

```
position: absolute;
min-height:100%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* Add in these */
-moz-background-size: cover;    /* four lines to */
-o-background-size: cover;      /* remove the white space*/
background-size: cover;         /* around images */
-webkit-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.5);
-moz-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.5);
-o-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.5);
-ms-filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.5);
transform: scale(1.1); /* get rid of that ugly border */
```

I don't have a lot of devices to test on, but I know it looks fine in: Chrome (MacOS), Firefox (MacOS), and Chrome (Android). I borrowed a friends iPhone to look at it, and the background image does not render at all.

In desktop Safari the image looks like this:

[image: desktop safari]
(Text removed)

This is what the page is supposed to look like:
[image: This is what it is supposed to look like.]

[Here's the html](http://pastebin.com/ZswQgdfW)

Comment: What is it *supposed* to look like? Where's the HTML and the rest of the CSS?

Comment: Sorry, the content of the site is rather political, so I decided to be safe. I edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: Where is all of your css?

Comment: Added with edit